# getting values an array in javascript according to other values

Tags: javascript

In this array `["mac","abcde","kalman","7.4099649898408115"]`

how can I get mac value is abcde and kalman value is 7.4099649898408115

I mean how can I select abcde when I want to get mac value in this string

for example

```js
console.log(mac) // and it returns abcde
```

How can I do this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: does it have to be an array? or could use an object instead?

Comment: Looks like you need an object instead of an array. Convert the array into an object literal: `{ mac: "abcde", kalman: "7.4099649898408115" }`

Comment: I can use an object

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the array to an object and take the wanted string as accessor of the object.

```js
var data = ["mac","abcde","kalman","7.4099649898408115"],
    object = {};

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    object[data[i]] = data[i + 1];
}

console.log(object.mac);    // access with dot
console.log(object['mac']); // access with brackets and string
console.log(object.kalman);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your array is made out of pairs. Every even index is the key you are looking for and every odd index is the corresponding value. A better datastructure would be an object (used as an dictionary) or a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). If you want to stick with an array, you can use `findIndex` and then simply add one to it.

```
let data = ["mac","abcde","kalman","7.4099649898408115"];
let searchKey = "mac";
const index = data.findIndex(e => e === searchKey);
const result = data[index + 1];
console.log(result); // prints "abcde"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use modulo and find each even index then make the change to your object

```js
const input = ["mac", "abcde", "kalman", "7.4099649898408115"]

const obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    obj[input[i]] = input[i + 1]
  }
}

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.mac)
```

Answer (score 1):

With reduce :

```js
const array = ["mac","abcde","kalman","7.4099649898408115"];

const object = array.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => 
    !(i%2) ? {...acc, [cur]: arr[i + 1]} : acc, {})

console.log(object)
console.log('max : ', object.mac)
console.log('kalman : ', object.kalman)
```